# Qt widget application runtime error : [The Application has requested the runtime to end in an unusual way]

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error

I am learning how to code in Qt and made a semi-Notepad like application.
It is working like a charm in my PC, but when I sent the executable file (I sent the whole debug folder with all the necessary .dll files in it) to my friend, their OS shows the following error:

> [This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.]

I compiled it using MinGW compiler and really can't see where the fault is.

Comment: See the Qt documentation for how to deploy Qt applications: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will prefer to do a Release compilation to provide a smaller executable and smaller set of DLLs.

As specified here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html you will need several DLLs located in your **Qt/MinGW/bin/** folder.

Most notably :

- platforms\qwindows.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll

You may also need the following, but you can try without :

- icudtXX.dll
- icuinXX.dll
- icuucXX.dll

Answer (score 0):

Trying to "Rebuild All" helped me to solve the issue. Although I had a runtime issue on the system where my application was built.